# PHP uploads image from same directory only

Tags: php, file-upload, path, directory

I have a PHP image upload script, something like this:

```
if($_FILES){
  if(in_array($_FILES["pic"]["type"]), ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"]){
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], "folder/"); 
 }  
}
```

The above method only works, if the image is in the same directory as that script, but if I want to upload an image from a desktop to where this `folder/` is located `c:/wamp/www/folder` then it won't work, as if it can't find the file?

Comment: "*if I want to upload an image from a desktop to where this folder/ is located c:/wamp/www/folder the it won't work*" — Could you clarify?

Comment: Wont `/folder/` work?

Comment: @AmalMurali I didn't say that. I said, where the php script is in

Comment: @AmalMurali It means I can't upload anything outside the folder from where this script is running from!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it's not working, is that you most likely have [`open_basedir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) in effect:

> open_basedir string

Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the

> specified directory-tree, including the file itself.
> When a script tries to access the filesystem, for example using include, or fopen(),
> the location of the file is checked. When the file is outside the
> specified directory-tree, PHP will refuse to access it.

You can set `open_basedir` settings in PHP directly, like:

```
ini_set('open_basedir', $config['base_path'] . '/:' . $config['tmp_path'] . '/:' . $config['logs_path'] . '/:' . $config['etc_path'] . '/');
```

###EDIT 1:
In case your `open_basedir` setting is not set, it can't be the issue. You must then look at the way you specify your path, for example you could have missing `/` at the end of the path, like `c:/wamp/www/folder/`.

To debug the problem, try to echo your path's chunks, like:

`echo $_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]` and see what you could be missing.

Read more about [`move_uploaded_file()`](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file) function and check at `safe_mode` setting as well:

> Note: move_uploaded_file() is both safe mode and open_basedir aware.
> However, restrictions are placed only on the destination path as to
> allow the moving of uploaded files in which filename may conflict with
> such restrictions. move_uploaded_file() ensures the safety of this
> operation by allowing only those files uploaded through PHP to be
> moved.

###EDIT 2:

Don't forget to restart your `apache` after editing *php.ini* file.

In addition double-check:

- `open_basedir` and ensure that `upload_tmp_dir` is inside this path. Try explicitly setting `c:/` to be inside of `open_basedir` using `:` as separator (like I exampled it above)
- [`upload_tmp_dir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) in *php.ini* or `ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','your/path/here/');`
- [`upload_max_filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) in *php.ini*

Comment: Ok, let's say that is the problem, and `open_basedir` equates to `no value` in `phpinfo()` so, how can I fix it ?

Comment: I altered apache's and php's `php.ini` files and set `open_basedir = '/'`. Now, I can upload files from anywhere from the entire `www` folder, but not from like `c:/`.

Comment: It doesn't completely work, but it does not at-least for all files found in `wamp` thanks. I never knew a thing about open_basedir before